# Частица- не- с прилагательными

Tags: орфография

Когда "не" пишется с прилагательным слитно, а когда раздельно? (Желательно правило)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Краткая схема такая.

Сначала определяем наличие обеих форм написания, а то и выбирать иногда нечего. Только слитно пишутся слова, которые не употребляются без НЕ (нелепый, неказистый, неожиданный). Только раздельно пишутся слова, которые не используют приставку НЕ для образования нового слова (не красный, не лесной, не узкий).

Если обе формы возможны, то основным является слитное написание НЕ. Раздельно НЕ пишется в отрицательных синтаксических конструкциях,  выбор которых нужно объяснить (противопоставление, усиление отрицания, отрицательное предложение): не большой, а маленький; нисколько не большой; дом не большой, просто кажется большим.

Остальное - у Лопатина и Розенталя.

Answer (score 0):

> Когда -не- пишется с прилагательным слитно , а когда раздельно?
>   (Желательно правило)

См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=76#pp76

Answer (score 0):

Егор, на этом форуме решаются конкретные вопросы. В вашем же случае всё довольно просто: открываете любой поисковик, набираете *орфография — правописание прилагательных с* ***НЕ*** и всё. А вот если вам что-то непонятно — это уже другое дело, тогда можете смело писать.